# Add line breaks when displaying a long string in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, html, uiwebview, line-breaks

When displaying a paragraph with some long strings without line breaks in an `UIWebView`, the size of the character is too small for reading, as show in the following pic. Is there anyway to automatically add line breaks in the long strings as in the `UILabel`? Thanks in advance!
[image]

ps. the `UIWebView` is used to display an email body.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

set the css as : `style="word-break:break-all"` to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Simply NO. UIWebView is made to parse HTML-Markup. The breaking has to be done there. \n will do it.

Other than that, you should rethink your HTML-Box-Model being responsive.

If you only want to display text, then use UITextView instead of UIWebView and switch to UIWebView, if its HTML. I think Mail.app on iOS does it like that. UITextView text is appropriately scaled.

Comment: but it is difficult to handle an Fw email with both text and html, while the text is a long string without link breaks.